# Load Specific Form Fields Upon Radio Button Selection

Tags: ajax, forms, yii

I am a fairly new user of Yii.. Have been using it for less than 2 months..
I am trying to do a registration form that upon loading, it only shows 2 radio buttons(say choice 1 is Person, choice 2 is Organization), when the user selects a choice i want to dynamically display the fields corresponding to his selection using ajax.

Note: I am using the yii-user extension, and I am intending to use the same table to store both Person & Organization users, since they only differ in 3 attributes.

I have been stuck with this problem for 2 days and am not able to solve it..

This is a snippet of my code:
registration.php (view)

```
<?php $this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - '.UserModule::t("Registration"); 
$this->breadcrumbs=array( 
        UserModule::t("Registration"), 
); 
?> 

<h1><?php echo UserModule::t("Registration"); ?></h1> 

<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('registration')): ?> 
<div class="success"> 
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('registration'); ?> 
</div> 
<?php else: ?> 

<div class="form"> 
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('UActiveForm', array( 
        'id'=>'registration-form', 
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
        'disableAjaxValidationAttributes'=>array('RegistrationForm_verifyCode'), 
        'clientOptions'=>array( 
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true, 
        ), 
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'), 
)); ?> 

        <p class="note"><?php echo UserModule::t('Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.'); ?></p> 

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model,$profile)); ?> 

    <div class="row"> 
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'profile_type', array(0=>'Person',1=>'Company'),array('separator'=>'', 'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'), 'onclick' =>CHtml::ajax(array("type"=>"GET", "url"=>array("registration/add"), "data"=>array('test'=>'js:this.value'), "update"=>"#test")))); ?> 

        </div>
```

RegistrationController.php

```
public function actionAdd() {  
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){   
                    $this->renderPartial("/user/test",array('model'=>$model),false,true);    
                    Yii::app()->end();               
            } 
    }
```

test.php

```
<?php 
$val = $_GET['test']; 

if($val == 1){ 
  echo "yes"; 
//nothing added yet 
} 
else{ 
        echo "no"; 
        ?> 
  <div class="row">  
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?> 
  </div> 
<div class="row"> 
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?> 
        </div> 

        <div class="row"> 
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?> 
        <p class="hint"> 
        <?php echo UserModule::t("Minimal password length 4 symbols."); ?> 
        </p> 
        </div> 

        <div class="row"> 
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyPassword'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword'); ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyPassword'); ?> 
        </div> 
<?php 

} 
?>
```

The erros am recieving when I select Person (choice 0) is the following:
Fatal error: Call to a member function labelEx() on a non-object in test.php

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The smoking gun is the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function labelEx() on a non-object in test.php` - it's telling you that `labelEx()` is not a method.  Looking at your `view.php`, you can see `labelEx()` is called as a method of `$form`.

The issue is that when the view `test.php` is being rendered, it has no idea about the `$form` you've created in `registration.php`.  `test.php` only knows about parameters you've passed to it (in this case, only `$model`).

Instead of using `$form->method()`, just use `CActiveForm::method` in your view, e.g.:

```
  <div class="row">  
    <?php 
        echo CActiveForm::labelEx($model,'username')
        echo CActiveForm::textField($model,'username');
        echo CActiveForm::error($model,'username');
    ?>
  </div>
```

I also combined your consecutive PHP blocks into a single block for easier reading/parsing/etc.

Comment: Thanks ernie, I tried that but it didn't work as well.. It returned this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in test.php

Comment: The error should have a line number - which line is it failing on?  What's the corresponding code that goes with that error?

Comment: Sorry.. the error wasn't in test.php but in CHtml.php on line 1197.. Bad mistake, the truth is am giving up on doing it this way.. Could it be really done with ajax?

Comment: Sure it could be done with AJAX, but you'll need to get it to work this way, before you can implement AJAX around it.  Your error suggests you have something wrong with your model.